# What reference power should I use?

Tags: homework

My professor asked me to convert following powers into decibels:
15W, 25W, 33W, 450mW, 24MW, 44 GW,120pW.
I know that decibels are about ratio power/reference_power.
I don't have reference power specified here. Is there something like default value? What should I do?

Comment: When no reference is specified, just use 1 watt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel_watt

dBW is relative to 1 W and dBm is relative to 1 mW.  I’d just make sure to provide the correct units, but maybe you could ask your teacher if it matters.